# Is it possible to set IPv6 proxy in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, ipv6

I tried to start chrome from command line

```
google-chrome --proxy-server="http://[<IPv6 address>]:<port>"
```

but it's does not working.

Is it possible to set proxy IPv6 in chrome?

Comment: Are you trying to use a link-local address?

Comment: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/HEAD/net/docs/proxy.md#bypass-rule_ipv6-address-range